# return results from a query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this results of a query:
(book_id, yr)

```
37 2014 
37 2012
35 2013
35 2012
35 2011
```

I would like to echo it like this

```
book id is 37 from 2014
editions available are 2014 and 2012
```

Comment: `distinct` or `group by` might be handy in this case, no?

Comment: Use `foreach` loop function and create an `index array` where `key` is your `book id` and `value` is your `edition` and check if `book id` already in your `array` update the `value` with comma seperated.

Comment: This might be useful `GROUP_CONCAT(editions ORDER BY editions ASC)`  and `GROUP BY book_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to group them inside a container, then just use `min` and `max`:

```
// grouping
$container = array();
while($row = your_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
    $container[$row['book_id']][] = $row['yr'];
}

// then comes the presentation
foreach($container as $book_id => $year) {
    $to = max($year);
    $from = min($year);
    echo "
        book id is {$book_id} <br/>
        editions available are {$to} and {$from} <br/><br/>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$years = array();
$id = 0;
foreach($row as $r){
  if( $r['book_id'] != $id && $id != 0){
    echo "book id is ".$id." editions available are ".implode('and ', $years);
    $years = array(); 
    $id = 0;
  }
  $id = $r['book_id'];
  $years[] =  $r['yr'];
}
echo "book id is ".$id." editions available are ".implode('and ', $years);
```

with that you iterate over you books and collect the years. Every time you find a new ID you echo the old entry with all the years you collectet. In the end you echo the last entry aswell.